# python image processing with numpy and scipy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm new to python image processing

how can I write a code to read and display an image ?

where the image should be saved in my pc  in order to be displayed ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a very basic question. Simple google search will give codes in almost any language. If you are starting with image processing I would suggest look at `Open CV`. This library provides all the functionality you need to perform image processing

A sample code of opencv would be

```
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('/path/to/file/on/system')

cv2.imshow('window name', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyWindow('window name')
```

Python also has a scikit-Image library you can look for codes there.

For learning OpenCV with python refer [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)